# Logrotate exits with return code 1 with CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, logrotate

I use a fake log file "log.php" as CodeIgniter writes date-named log files.

```
/home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log.php {
        daily
        rotate 31
        missingok
        notifempty
        su boxu boxu
        #create 640 boxu boxu
        nocreate
        nocompress
        extension .php
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
}
```

Could this be the reason logrotate exits with return code 1?

```
 rotating pattern: /home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log.php  after 1 days (31 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log.php
  log needs rotating
rotating log /home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log.php, log->rotateCount is 31
Converted ' -%Y-%m-%d' -> '-%Y-%m-%d'
dateext suffix '-2017-03-27'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
removing /home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log-2017-02-24.php
removing old log /home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log-2017-02-24.php
destination /home/boxu/website/html/protected/application/logs/log-2017-03-27.php already exists, skipping rotation
```

I suspect the last line. This is live run with -v

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```php
/*
a php solution
$dirin the directory to check
$numToKeep - keep the latest X number of files
*/
function cleanUpFiles($dirin,$numToKeep) {
    // 1- get a list of file for the directory

    $f1 = new FilesystemIterator($dirin , FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    gjLog($dirin . " number of files : " . iterator_count($f1),'clean.log');

    $gjcount=0; // start at

    if(iterator_count($f1) < $numToKeep){
        gjLog('Number of Files less than number to keep: ' . $numToKeep. ' Nothing to unlink' .PHP_EOL,'clean.log');
        return;
    }

    // 2- create an array of files to sort by Modified Time in step 3

    $thefiles = array();
    foreach($f1 as $fileinfo) {
        $akey = $f1->getFileName();
        if((strtolower($akey)) != 'index.html') {
            $thefiles[$akey] = $f1->getMTime();
        }
    }

    // 3- sort the files by date - descending  newest first

    arsort($thefiles);

    // 4- start at 0, after 10 files delete the rest

    foreach ($thefiles as $key => $value) {
        if($numToKeep < $gjcount){
            $killme = $dirin . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $key;
            gjLog('unlinking these files: ' . $killme ,'clean.log');
            if(!unlink($killme)) {
                $err ='unable to unlink '. $killme .PHP_EOL;
                gjLog($err,'clean.log');
                // when in cron job, I check for Fatal in the mail
                echo $err. ' Fatal Error in' . __FILE__ . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        $gjcount++;
    }
}

// cleanup application logs

$dirin = '/var/www/html/application/logs';
$numToKeep=30; // total number to keep
cleanUpFiles($dirin,$numToKeep);
</pre>
```

Comment: This does not really address the `logrotate` issue.